# CentOS Insufficient space in download directory /var/cache/yum/base/packages

Tags: centos, partition, yum, cleanup

I was trying to **yum install libpcap** when I got

```
 Error Downloading Packages:
  14:libpcap-0.9.4-15.el5.i386: Insufficient space in download directory /var/cache/yum/base/packages
    * free   0 
    * needed 108 k
```

Here's output from **df -h**:

```
Filesystem            Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda1              20G   19G     0 100% /
/dev/sda3             202G   38G  154G  20% /home
tmpfs                 1.5G     0  1.5G   0% /dev/shm
```

And **fdisk -l**:

```
Disk /dev/sda: 250.0 GB, 250000000000 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 30394 cylinders
Units = cylinders of 16065 * 512 = 8225280 bytes

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1   *           1        2611    20972826   83  Linux
/dev/sda2            2612        3251     5140800   82  Linux swap / Solaris
/dev/sda3            3252       30394   218026147+  83  Linux
```

I have launched **yum clean all** with no success clearing up space.

Please advise. 
Thanks.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Your `/` mount is full.

First, verify `/tmp` is empty.

Second, empty the contents of `/var/cache/yum/base/packages`. <sub><sup>(Or consider just moving the contents while verifying the below procedure on your system.)</sup></sub>

Then try `bind` mounting space from `/home` to `/var/cache/yum/base/packages` thusly:

```
mount --bind /home/yum /var/cache/yum/base/packages
```

Then add an entry at the bottom of your `/etc/fstab` like this:

```
/home/yum /var/cache/yum/base/packages none,rw bind 0 0
```

Once the bind mounts are setup, running a `df -h` will show `/var/cache/yum/base/packages` to have boku space. Then run `yum` and verify everything is copasetic.

Answer (score 10):

I do agree that you need to clean some stuff up in /, but have you tried changing

> cachedir=/var/cache/yum

in /etc/yum.conf