# insufficient space in download directory /var/cache/yum/updates/packages

Tags: installation, yum, cache, tmp, cleanup

I try to install vim-enhanced using `#yum install vim-enhanced` I got an error like this `insufficient space in download directory /var/cache/yum/updates/packages` I found some answers to the [this question](https://serverfault.com/questions/145064/centos-insufficient-space-in-download-directory-var-cache-yum-base-packages) but I did not understood because I'm very new to linux environment, I'm currently use Fedora 18, please can anyone help me to figure out this

Comment: Do you have enough space...? `df -h`

Comment: I attached a like: please refer https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B9tyULY_FLygT0p2U0ktWE8zUUE/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 4):

It seems like your `rootfs` (`/`) is at 100%! Try cleaning it up first, maybe try `yum clean all`.

Comment: thank you, it works fine, I'm using vmbox with 8GB virtual heard drive but root directory content 4.1GB ? I cannot understand why, is there anyway to increase the virtual disk space in vmbox ?
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B9tyULY_FLygVE9DTEh1eE1UZVk/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: It'd probably easier to attach another storage and mount it separately (outside of root). Try use Google, search for: `virtualbox add storage linux`.

Comment: +1 That did it at first but when it came time to download the dependency it gave the same error. I deleted a huge zip file, all I am trying to do is install python26

Answer (score 2):

You're out of space. Free up some or get a bigger disk.